# Finding the proof of a bound on the roots of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots, upper-lower-bounds

G.S. Carr's "**Synopsis of Elementary Results in Pure Mathematics**" mentions the following bound on the roots of a polynomial in its article 449:

If $x^{n-r}$ and $x^{n-s}$ are the highest negative terms in $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$ respectively, $(1+ \sqrt[r] p)$ and $-(1+ \sqrt[s] q)$ are limits of the roots.

Of course ,$f(x) := x^n +p_1x^{n-1}+...+p_n$, and $p,q$ are the coefficients of $x^{n-r}, x^{n-s}$ respectively, i.e. $|p_r|, |p_s|$ in truth.

This bound resembles both the Cauchy and the Lagrange-Zassenhauss bounds. But I couldn't find it in a textbook or on the net. Any ideas how to prove it? Thanks!

Comment: Does "highest negative term" mean that $p_r < 0$ and $p_i \ge 0$ for $i <  r$? If so, what is the meaning of $\sqrt[r]{p_r}$ when $r$ is even?

Comment: @Paul Frost, the book is quite old, and terminology quite outdated, so I am going to mention the way it words the Cauchy bound: " If the greatest negative coefficients in $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$ be $p$ and $q$ respectively, then $p+1$ and $-(q+1)$ are the limits of the roots."

Comment: This has a different flavor. It seems that $p$ is the maximum of all values $-p_i$ with $p_i < 0$. You should try to clarify whether it has the same interpretation in your case.